# sqlite get name of attached databases

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, command, sqlite-shell

How do I get the name of the Attached databases in SQLite?

I've tried looking into:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
```

But there doesn't seem to be any information there about the attached databases.

I attach the databases with the command:

```
ATTACH DATABASE <fileName> AS <DBName>
```

It would be nice to be able to retrieve a list of the FileNames or DBNames attached.

I'm trying to verify if a database was correctly attached without knowing its schema beforehand.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
PRAGMA database_list;
```

> **[PRAGMA database_list;](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_database_list)**
>   This pragma works like a query **to return one row for each database
>   attached to the current database connection.** The second column is the
>   "main" for the main database file, "temp" for the database file used
>   to store TEMP objects, or the name of the ATTACHed database for other
>   database files. The third column is the name of the database file
>   itself, or an empty string if the database is not associated with a
>   file.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`.database`](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#querying_the_database_schema) command.

Comment: Aren't these dot commands like `.database`, `.open xyz` etc. proprietary to the command line interface from SQLite Tools?

Answer (score 3):

This query below can get the name of attached databases:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pragma_database_list;
```