# How to get sqlite database path from sql.DB instance

Tags: sqlite, go, sqlcipher

I want to get the path or even the connection string of a `sql.DB` instance. The package I'm writing doesn't know what the database path is and the application may have multiple database files. However I need to be able to map a specific database to a specific buffered channel, and ignore any additional calls for a database the package has already seen.

The application uses the `github.com/mutecomm/go-sqlcipher` driver to instantiate the database, if that makes any difference.

Is it possible to discriminate between instances of `sql.DB` based on the file path of the source database? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51952530/13860

Comment: This may be an XY Problem. Can you explain what you're using these buffered channels for?

Comment: If your goal is to know which database you're connected to, this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072554/sqlite-get-name-of-attached-databases  But note: There's a potential many-to-one relationship between *sql.DB instances and sqlite databases.

Comment: Hey @Flimzy thank you for your reply. I'm modifying an application that contains a package that manages settings, this package has this func `New(db *sql.DB) (Settings, error)` . The package will take any db and return a Settings struct that has settings table related funcs.

But the application can have multiple databases each with its own settings table. The application frustratingly instantiates the Settings struct in multiple places by different services that want to access the settings, and I need to trigger events when certain settings are changed. The channel is the event stack

Comment: For that, then `PRAGMA database_list` is probably the best answer.